# Why does turning on password protected sharing have no effect under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, permissions, network-shares

I'm trying to restrict access to a share in a workplace network using username/password credentials. For that I've added a new user via `netplwiz` that belongs to the *Distributed COM-User* group according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlHCropfUSA). In the advanced sharing settings I have the following settings under both public and private:

- Network discovery: On
- File and printer sharing: On
- Public folder: Off
- Password protected sharing: On
- Allow windows to manage homegroup connections: On

In the sharing settings of my shared folders I have added reading permissions for my new user account `test01`, and under the security tab I have added the groups *Authenticated Users* and *Users*, and the new user account.

The problem is this: The other computer discovers the share, but it never prompts to ask for a password. When I leave the *Everyone* group in the permissions dialog of the share, I can simply access and view all files in the folder without password. When I just leave user `test01` in the list, I cannot access the share at all on the other computer. It simply displays the following error message:

> **Windows cannot access \\Server\TestShare**
>   You do not have permissions to access \\Server\TestShare. Contact your network administrator to request access.

What is wrong?

Comment: Ensure you don't have any (wrong/old) saved credentials (in Windows' Credential Manager) on the client box you're trying to access the share with.  Also, is this a Workgroup, or Domain-based "workplace network"?

Comment: I couldn't even once enter a password on the client box since it never prompted me to. It is a workplace network without a domain but with a workgroup.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Is workplace network always in relation to a domain?

Comment: Never mind. The problem was elsewhere. The user/password combination I've tested it with matched exactly the current user on the client box, so apparently Windows 7 does silently check these credentials against the host machine so that it was immediately logged in without asking for the password. Could that be?